# reset a pointer for a for-loop in php

Tags: php, for-loop

given the following code

```
<?php
$a = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
$c=0;
foreach($a as $v){
    if($v==5&&$c==0){
        $c=1;
        reset($a);
    }
    var_dump($v);
}
```

How do I reset the pointer so it will print 1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,6 ?

I know that in this case I can simply

```
<?php
$a = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
$c=0;
for($i=0;$i<count($a);++$i){
    $v = $a[$i];
    if($v==5&&$c==0){
        $c=1;
        $i=-1;  //because of the loop ++$i
    }
    var_dump($v);
}
```

But I have a much more complex piece of code and the solution is not as simple as rewrite the loop (not numeric keys).

Any PHP guru out there that can help me here ?

Comment: Your first example should work. `reset()` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) is the function for the case.

Comment: it should, but it doesn't !!

Comment: fyi, How a 'foreach' actually 'works' is 'interesting, maybe: [How 'foreach' actually works](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057671/how-foreach-actually-works). May i suggest that you do not adjust the 'internal pointer' in a 'foreach loop'? There are other 'loop' constructs that work fine when the 'internal pointer' is reset.

Comment: If I could make it work without reset it I would.  I will check out the link, thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### NOTE: Answer uses function deprecated as of PHP 7.2

As @TheodoreR.Smith pointed out in the comments. list() = each() will not work for any PHP version >= 7.2. See:

[How can I update code that uses the deprecated each() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46492621/how-can-i-update-code-that-uses-the-deprecated-each-function)

### Original Answer for version < 7.2

As documented:

> Note: When foreach first starts executing, the internal array pointer is automatically reset to the first element of the array. This means that you do not need to call reset() before a foreach loop.
>
> As foreach relies on the internal array pointer, **changing it within the loop may lead to unexpected behavior**.

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Not sure what "unexpected behavior" is, as I've never tried this...but maybe safer to manually use each()...also more clear in your code.

```
reset($a);
while(list($key, $val) = each($a)) {
    if($val==5&&$c==0){
        $c=1;
        reset($a);
    }
    var_dump($val);
}
```

**Foreach Issues Explained**

I thought I had seen before that you couldn't rely on the internal pointer in the foreach...but couldn't find it in the documentation this time...only "unexpected results".  However, thanks to a commenter, I found the text that used to be in the foreach:

> Unless the array is referenced, foreach **operates on a copy of the specified array** and not the array itself. foreach has some side effects on the array pointer. Don't rely on the array pointer during or after the foreach without resetting it."

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php#114759

Comment: The `while()` with the `each()` is really the best solution here.

Comment: I was actually going to add that to the code, that it is a feasible solution, but because the `foreach` relies on the internal array pointer I was thinking that a `reset` should have worked.  Thank you

Comment: @Fabrizio, yeah...it's actually confusing me a bit...I thought it had said it used a different pointer somewhere else...based on that documentation, I agree it would seem that reset() "should" work.  So, I'm mostly going off the "unexpected behavior" aspect in the comments.

Comment: @Fabrizio, okay, updated my answer with a possible solution to try...try referencing your array in the foreach.

Comment: `Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '&' in [...][...] on line 3` --> this error occurs on your 2nd example.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel, thanks for the FYI -- hate examples that make me look stupid :)...that's what I get for not trying it out first...wonder why the documentation implied you could reference it then?  In any case, removed that example and I'll stick with the answer that you just need to use `each()`.

Comment: @KevinNelson I think the documentation meant `foreach($a as &$v)`. But don't worry, mine made me look stupid a little aswell. Alternatively, you can try to store a reference and reset the reference (or add an element to the beggining of the array.)

Comment: `each` was removed in PHP 8. This answer no longer works at all.

Comment: @TheodoreR.Smith, thanks for the note.  I added a warning to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you are a fan of OOP, you can use the [ArrayIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayiterator.php) class.

It has the method [`rewind()`](http://php.net/manual/en/arrayiterator.rewind.php) which is the same as the [`reset()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php).

```php
$a=array(1,2,3,4,5,6);//or $a=range(1,6);

$i=new ArrayIterator($a);

$c=0;

foreach($i as $k=>$v)
{
    if($v==5&&$c==0)
    {
        $c=1;
        $i->rewind();
    }
    var_dump($v);
}

unset($i);//delete the iterator, to free memory
```

You can test it online on http://writecodeonline.com/php/ or on http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/

[@KevinNelson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/482256/kevin-nelson)'s answer is the right way to go, but it won't be obvious for the untrained eye.

---

There's a problem with this code.
Due to the iteration, the number 1 won't be echoed the 2nd time around.

But I've got 2 *franken-solutions*!

**Solution 1:** jump over an ignorable element, using the method [`next()`](http://php.net/manual/en/arrayiterator.next.php)

```php
$a=array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6);//or $a=range(0,6);

$i=new ArrayIterator($a);

$c=0;

$i->next();//jumps over the 1st element

foreach($i as $k=>$v)
{
    if($v==5&&$c==0)
    {
        $c=1;
        $i->rewind();
    }
    var_dump($v);
}

unset($i);
```

**Solution 2:** create an element with 'falsy' value (`0`, `null`, `false`, `''`...) and ignore it inside the loop

```php
$a=array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6);//or $a=range(0,6);

$i=new ArrayIterator($a);

$c=0;

foreach($i as $k=>$v)
{
    if($v==5&&$c==0)
    {
        $c=1;
        $i->rewind();
    }
    if($v)var_dump($v);
}

unset($i);
```

Comment: Strangely enough that skips the first value the second time around: https://eval.in/312989

Comment: @jeroen I've somewhat fixed it with some * franken-code*.