# How to remove each() from php codes

Tags: php, each, deprecated

I am using a 2008 php program to take an image, annotate it and create a thumbnail of the image.

The program works but throws a notice that the each function is deprecated, and the PHP docs say it will stop working in PHP 8.

Here is the line with the each

```
 while (list($numl, $line) = each($lines)) {
```

How do I get rid of the each?

Comment: Seems like you just need a foreach loop?

Comment: Use [`foreach`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve this deprecated function each php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46492621/how-to-resolve-this-deprecated-function-each-php)

Answer (score 1):

Use `foreach` instead.

```
foreach ($lines as $num1 => $line) {
```