# Temporarily fix each() function in php 8 (solved)

Tags: php, each, php-8

I'm changing server, I switch from centos to ubuntu 20.04 with php 8.

Many of my sites on the server use this old class: https://github.com/xmyl/Snoopy-2.0/blob/master/Snoopy.class.php

The sites have been there for a long time and I use this class to access the various username and password protected areas of my affiliate programs, read the xml/rss/csv files, and process them automatically.

The problem is that this class often uses the each() function which was previously deprecated and now eliminated in php 8.

I need to change the server now (it wasn't expected), and get this class to work somehow. Afterwards I can calmly review all the scripts, update them, modify them etc, but now I need a quick and easy solution to make it work.

I tried changing each() to current(), and then to add this:

```
/**
 * Adds the depreciated each() function back into 7.2
 */
if (!function_exists('each')) {
    function each($arr) {
        $key = key($arr);
        $result = ($key === null) ? false : [$key, current($arr), 'key' => $key, 'value' => current($arr)];
        next($arr);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

It didn't work much, the script ends in: Fatal error: Allowed memory size....

There is a quick and easy way to get it to work? (temporarily) Or a quick alternative that works as well as snoopy?

---

Just to close... solved in 5 seconds... the solution...

```
if (!function_exists('each')) {
    function each(array &$array) {
        $value = current($array);
        $key = key($array);

        if (is_null($key)) {
            return false;
        }

        // Move pointer.
        next($array);

        return array(1 => $value, 'value' => $value, 0 => $key, 'key' => $key);
    }
}
```

https://gist.github.com/k-gun/30dd2bf8b22329a2dbc11a045aed3859

Comment: Is this a shared host?  Often providers give you the option to choose the PHP version you run on.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/k-gun/30dd2bf8b22329a2dbc11a045aed3859

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46493221/222564

Comment: Barman -> Seems to work... I've been looking for 8 hours... fixed in 5 sec... :O... Thanks.

Comment: Yours works if you pass by reference `function each(&$arr) {`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I update code that uses the deprecated each() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46492621/how-can-i-update-code-that-uses-the-deprecated-each-function)

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the array to your `each()` function by reference. The way it is currently written the array is copied into the function, and that copy is having it's internal pointer incremented without affecting the original.

```
function each(&$arr) {
 /*...*/
}
```